# How extract from UITableView data (UIImage and String) to another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4, xcode9

I want to pass the storage data contained in a TableView and pass it to another ViewController. My customCell has an UIImage and a String.
When the user press the cell I want to show a "detail view controller" with the UIImage and a label containing the info of the cell selected.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var dataTableView: UITableView!

var myList = [dataList]()

var textToBeSent: String = ""

var selectedImage: UIImage?
var selectedLabel: String?

//Load Items To List

func loaditems(){
    let item1 = dataList(photoList: UIImage.self(), itemDescription: "Descripcion Aqui")
    let item2 = dataList(photoList: UIImage.self(), itemDescription: "Aqui tmb")

    myList += [item1,item2]
}

//var list = ["Documento 1", "Documento 2", "Documento 3"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let savedData = loadSavedItems(){
        myList += savedData
    } else {

    loaditems()
    }


    //dataTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "reusablecell")


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return myList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "prototype", for: indexPath) as! PrototypeCell

    let itemsinCell = myList[indexPath.row]

    cell.imageItem.image = itemsinCell.photoList
    cell.itemDescription.text = String(itemsinCell.itemDescription)

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete{
        myList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        dataTableView.reloadData()
    }

    saveToSavedData()
}
```

Here is the func where I want to pass the data of a certain cell.
The data is from a Swift file stored in a "DataList" using aDecoder NSCoder.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    print("Row \(indexPath.row) selected")
    selectedImage! = myList[indexPath.row].photoList
    selectedLabel! = myList[indexPath.row].itemdescription
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "selectedRowSegue", sender: myList[indexPath.row])
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "selectedRowSegue"){
        let chosenRowViewController = segue.destination as! chosenRowViewController
        chosenRowViewController.image3 = selectedImage?.photoList
        chosenRowViewController.label3 = selectedLabel?.itemDescription
    }
}
```

Unwind a segue in order to fill up the cells with data from previous
ViewController:

```
//Unwinde Segue
@IBAction func unWindlToList(sender: UIStoryboardSegue){
    if let sourceViewController = sender.source as? ProcessViewController, let item = sourceViewController.item{
        let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: myList.count, section: 0)
        myList.append(item)
        dataTableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
    saveToSavedData()
}
//Archive Data
func saveToSavedData(){
    NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(myList, toFile: (dataList.fileFolder?.path)!)
}
//Unarchive Data
func loadSavedItems() -> [dataList]?{
    return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: (dataList.fileFolder?.path)!) as? [dataList]
}

}

class PrototypeCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var itemDescription: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var imageItem: UIImageView!

}
```

Comment: Hi Mike! it seems like I'm doing that but thats no happening. I think the code is correct but it just doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things that stand out.

1- `var myList = [dataList]()` dataList is a `Class`, classes should be capitalized. It should be `var myList = [DataList]()`

2- You have this as a class property but it's not used anywhere in the code you posted so why did you add it and what is it's purpose? `var textToBeSent: String = ""`

3- You have these 2 class property variables

```
var selectedImage: UIImage?
var selectedLabel: String?
```

to hold the data from `[myList]` but you really don't need them because you can just access the data from `[myList]` using `dot notation` inside `prepareForSegue` (read the commented out code in prepareForSegue).

4- In prepareForSegue you have `let chosenRowViewController = segue.destination as! chosenRowViewController`. ChosenRowViewController is a class and it should be capitalized like so:

```
let chosenRowViewController = segue.destination as! ChosenRowViewController // it's capitalized after the as!
```

Here's the code a little cleaned up.

```
@IBOutlet weak var dataTableView: UITableView!

var myList = [DataList]()

func loaditems(){
    let item1 = dataList(photoList: UIImage.self(), itemDescription: "Descripcion Aqui")
    let item2 = dataList(photoList: UIImage.self(), itemDescription: "Aqui tmb")

    myList.append(item1)
    myList.append(item2)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // everything you already have inside here...
}

// your tableView datasource methods...
```

5- Since your using `prepareForSegue` you don’t need `didSelectRowAt indexPath`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "selectedRowSegue"){

        // get the indexPath for the selectedRow
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow

        let chosenRowViewController = segue.destination as! ChosenRowViewController
        chosenRowViewController.image3 = myList[indexPath!.row].photoList // use dot notation to access the photoList property
        chosenRowViewController.label3 = myList[indexPath!.row].itemDescription  // use dot notation to access the itemDescription property
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Lance, the code seems right but it doesn't work tho. I´d think that I need didSelectRowAt in order to specify the content of the cell selected (correct me if I'm wrong) Please if you have another idea it will help me a lot, Im loosing my mind here.

Comment: Try and be specific as to why it’s not working. Is it that the ChosenRowViewController isn’t getting pushed on? Is it getting pushed on but the data isn’t getting sent? Or is it both? You should also add the DataList data model. The more you show and the more info you add about the problem the easier it is to debug for you.

Answer (score 1):

just replace `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` function with below code

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "selectedRowSegue"), let list = sender as? dataList {
            let chosenRowViewController = segue.destination as! chosenRowViewController
            chosenRowViewController.image3 = list.photoList
            chosenRowViewController.label3 = list.itemDescription 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer iParesh, the code seems right but it doesn't work tho. I dont know what is happening, surly a mistake from my side. But please if you have another idea it will help me a lot

Answer (score 0):

You have made a mistake in your `didSelectRowAt`, while calling `performSegue` you have to pass the controller which is the `sender`, in your case it is your current `UIVIewController`, so you have to write `self` as sender controller. So your corrected methog will look like below code snippet:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    print("Row \(indexPath.row) selected")
    selectedImage! = myList[indexPath.row].photoList
    selectedLabel! = myList[indexPath.row]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "selectedRowSegue", sender: self)
}
```